# Adding Reachability class fails when I am trying to build

Tags: iphone, ios, linker-errors

I have added the SystemConfiguration framework. I am deploying against targets from 3.2 and higher. Have I forgotten to add something?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: please check your internet connection or carrier network, this _OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability means reachability issue to internet for the device

Comment: Please have look on this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804526/reachability-ios-5-1-ipad

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Okay, the clues are all in the error report you have posted.

While linking (the message is from the linker **ld**) which occurs after compilation of all the symbols across your project, the message is saying

"In AppDelegate, you have referenced a class object called **Reachability**"

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability"
```

and as far as the linker is concerned **Reachability** is undefined.

So, check that Reachability is being compiled in your project. The are a couple of ways to do this. Perhaps the most clear way is to
[image]

1 select the project file in the navigation pane

2 select the target

3 select **Build Phases**

4 Expand the **Compile Sources** section

*Now check the list of sources that will be compiled for your missing class, in your case **Reachability.m**

If it is missing, use the **+** button to add the file to the target.

Another way is to

[image]

1 select the file you think is not being compiled

2 open the utilities panel

3 select the file inspector tab

There will be a checkbox for each target in your project and you can easily see if your **.m** file is being compiled for each/all targets or not.

Answer (score 1):

You might have forgotten to include the Reachability classes in your project!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I upgraded to the newest version of Mixpanel.  The error read:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Mixpanel.o
```

You can follow Damo's solution until the last step, and then instead of expanding the **Compile Sources** section, you have to expand the **Link Binary With Libraries** section instead, and add the **CoreTelephony.framework** source which contains **CTTelephonyNetworkInfo**.

You can read more about the CTTelephonyNetworkInfo class reference on Apple's official website here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/Reference/Reference.html